# How to check a list of all commands from discord

Tags: python, command, discord, self, discord.py

I'm trying to check If some argument is a command from my server

```
async def test(self, ctx, *, cmd: str):

    if cmd in self.bot.commands:
```

What should I do?
The self.bot.commands get a list of commands objects not the names..

Comment: In the async branch commands have a name attribute and if the same is in the rewrite branch (you can verify with a print statement), then you can create a list of names to check your argument value. Try something like `l1 = [n.name for n in self.bot.commands]` and then `if cmd in l1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that `self.bot.commands` returns a list of [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands).
One such [command object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Command) has a [name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Command.name) attribute. So you can create a function to check if the message (name) corresponds with a name of an existing command:

```
def command_name_exists(name):
    for command in self.bot.commands:
        if name == command.name:
            return True
    return False
```